# ¿Cómo agregar características y hacer compatible un simple slider a la nueva versión jQuery?

Tags: jquery

El siguiente código solo funciona en la versión de jQuery `1.7.2` pero en la actual versión de jQuery no funciona.

Existen muchos `div` en la estructura `HTML` a lo mejor un contenedor encargado de deslizar el slider con un `div` especifico así `<div class="item>"` sería mucho mejor.

```js
$(".slider .content-slides").width($(".slider .content-slides").children().size() * $(".slider .content-slides").width());


function slideStart()
{
    curPage = ((index) % $(".slider .content-slides").children().size()) + 1;
    $(".slider .content-slides").animate({
        "left": -($(".slider .content-slides div:nth-child(" + curPage + ")").position().left)
    });
    $(".slider .content-pagination div").removeClass("active-marker");
    $(".slider .content-pagination div:nth-child(" + curPage + ")").addClass("active-marker");
    index++;
}


$(".slider .content-pagination li a").click(function(){
    index = $(this).attr("href");
    clearInterval(islider);
    slideStart();
    islider = setInterval("slideStart()", 2500);
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    index = 0;
    islider = setInterval("slideStart()", 2500);
});
```

```css
.slider {padding: 0; height: 150px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 270px;}
.slider .content-slides {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.slider .content-slides div {width: 270px; height: 150px; position: relative; float: left; list-style: none;}
.slider .content-slides div img {width: 270px; height: 150px; display: block;}
.slider .content-slides div .desc {position: absolute; font-size: 90%; background: #999; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 0 0 5px;}
.slider .content-slides div .desc * {color: #fff; width: 200px; margin: 5px 10px; line-height: 1.1em;}
.slider .content-pagination {text-align: right; position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; z-index: 5;}
.slider .content-pagination div {float: none; display: inline; font-size: 0.75em; padding: 0.25em;}
.slider .content-pagination div a {width: 7px; height: 7px; border-radius: 7px; background-color: #ccc; overflow: hidden; line-height: 10px; font-size: 1px; text-indent: -999em; display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1;}
.slider .content-pagination div.active-marker a,
.slider .content-pagination div a:hover {background-color: #08c; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="content-slides">
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/150/sports/1/" alt="" />
            <div class="desc">
                <h3>Heading 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/150/sports/2/" alt="" />
            <div class="desc">
                <h3>Heading 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/150/sports/3/" alt="" />
            <div class="desc">
                <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/150/sports/4/" alt="" />
            <div class="desc">
                <h3>Heading 4</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/150/sports/5/" alt="" />
            <div class="desc">
                <h3>Heading 5</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Anteriormente esto:

```
<ul class="content-pagination">
    <li><a href="0"></a></li>
    <li><a href="1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="3"></a></li>
    <li><a href="4"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Eran los controles ****** del slider.

Pero mejor sería agregarlos en un `div` así:

```
<div id="slider-controls" class="slider-controls"></div>
```

Y poder agregar los botones izquierda y derecha mediante igual un `div`

```
  <div id="slider-prev">
    <a class="a-left"><i class="arrow-left"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div id="slider-next">
    <a class="a-right"><i class="arrow-right"></i></a>
  </div>
```

La cual encontré cierto código completo y incompleto debe unirse e adaptarse a todo el código del slider para que funcione.

```
  // Controles del Slider
  $('#slider-controls').html(output).on('click', 'div', function (e){
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log("cargando....."+$this.index());
    if (currentSlider !== $this.index()) {
      changePanel($this.index());
    };
  });

  //Buttons control paginations prev
  $('.a-left').on('click', function(e) {
    var left = currentSlider - 1;
    changePanel(left);
  });

  //Buttons control paginations next
  $('.a-right').on('click', function(e) {
    var right = currentSlider + 1;
    changePanel(right);
  });
}
```

¿Me pueden ayudar a armar un sencillo slider compatible?

Comment: gracias amigo, amigo me puedes ayudar por favor en agregar los circulos y los dos botones izquierda y derecha, parte de ese código ya lo encontré, peor no se adaptarlo, el código este slider lo encontré en la web.

Comment: No se ejecuta en JSFiddle, muestra un mensaje subrayado, como avisando un error `setInterval` puedes observar en: https://jsfiddle.net/ph2q7wyx/2/

Comment: Hola, no se si te sirvió la respuesta de Jorge, pero si no, para poderte ayudar mejor quizás ayudaría que pudieras 'colgar' en algún sitio un ejemplo sencillo del slider funcionando (con la versión anterior de jquery)

Comment: he corregido tu código y actualizado mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia todas tus referencias de la función `size().` por `length` ya que en las nuevas versiones de jQuery ya no funciona. Espero haberte ayudado.

He visto tu ejemplo de Fiddle ya que es lo unico que tengo ahora para poder ayudarte y he corregido el codigo, hay ciertas cosas que tienes que cambiar, te lo pongo aqui corregido:

```
$(".slider .content-slides").width($(".slider .content-slides").children().length * $(".slider .content-slides").width());


function slideStart()
{
    curPage = ((index) % $(".slider .content-slides").children().length) + 1;
    $(".slider .content-slides").animate({
        "left": -($(".slider .content-slides div:nth-child(" + curPage + ")").position().left)
    });
    $(".slider .content-pagination div").removeClass("active-marker");
    $(".slider .content-pagination div:nth-child(" + curPage + ")").addClass("active-marker");
    index++;
}



$(".slider .content-pagination li a").click(function(){
    index = $(this).attr("href");
    clearInterval(islider);
    slideStart();
    islider = setInterval(slideStart, 2500);
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    index = 0;
    islider = setInterval(slideStart, 2500);
});
```